# How to use ANT in Cloudbees

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to move an existing ANT build script (build.xml) into Cloudbees for CI using Jenkins. I setup the project repository using GitHub. The build pulls the repository into the Cloudbees Workspace successfully, but then fails with this message.

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file /scratch/jenkins/workspace/project/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
```

I'm not too familiar with this, but from what I can tell (thanks Google) it's because Cloudbees uses Maven instead of ANT. Is there a way that I can change Jenkins to run the ANT build script instead of using Maven? Or a simple way to execute my ANT scripts from Maven? Any help here would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a Maven POM file if your project is Ant-based.

It sounds like you created a Maven job in Jenkins. Delete it and create a *free-style* job instead, then (as @thekbb says) click *Add build step* and select *Invoke Ant* and configure as needed.

Comment: You're right! This is even better, the build finishes faster without having to build an empty Maven job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ant support is provided by teh [ant plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin), I think you get this automatically when installing jenkins.  In your jenkins job, add a build step of type 'Invoke Ant' and provide the target.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to create a minimal POM file, on to fixing the next error! Thanks for the help.